# Timing issues with angular asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I've had weird timing issues with async calls using Angular.

I have an array of ids:

```
set = [1,2]
```

I loop over this set and make an async call for each ID:

```
promises = []
for id in set
  d = $q.defer()
  promises.push d.promise
  mySvc.asyncGetObject id
  .then (results) ->
     console.log results, id
     # results doesnt correspond with the ID
```

In the .then() block, when I expect to get id==2's object, I am actually getting id==1's object. I have traced this thoroughly and it doesn't make any sense. I looked at the network panel - the HTTP call is made correctly. The results I am getting from the call do not match up with the results I get in the code.

What could be causing this? I had an issue in the past where I was trying to update a number of HTML elements, and I had to wrap one or two of the calls in setTimeout, otherwise they wouldn't execute. I don't know if this is related, but it is frustrating.

Comment: This smells like the deferred anti-pattern to me.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: I don't see how this exemplifies the deferred antipattern.  I am looping over  an asynchronous method to get several objects, saving the promises and using $q.all() later to do postprocessing of the returned data. I don't see how I could have used promise chaining to accomplish this.

Comment: Push the promises returned from the `then` calls, if you want you can also `map` over the array to an array of promises with then chaining :)

Comment: I need to process the result from the then() call. After the async call finishes, I do some stuff with the result, and then resolve the processed result. After all of the promises have resolved, then $q.all does something with all of the gathered resolves.

If I push the implicit promise returned by .then(), how can I return a value? I will just know that the async method completed, but I wouldn't be able to access the result of .then().

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying. I should be returning the value in the .then() call rather than using a deferred to pass it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop bodies (in CoffeeScript or JavaScript) aren't closures, so when the async callback is executed, the `id` will have the value of the last element in the `set`.

Here is a [good article about this](http://farmdawgnation.com/blog/2014/5/9/gotchas-loops-in-coffeescript-are-not-closures).

In your example, something along these lines should do it:

```
promises = []
for id in set
  d = $q.defer()
  promises.push d.promise
  do(id)
    mySvc.asyncGetObject id
      .then (results) ->
         console.log results, id
  , id
```

Comment: Thank you. This has been driving me batty.